# github desktop error “The repository does not seem to exist anymore. You may not have access, or it may have been deleted or renamed.”

Tags: github, github-pages, github-for-windows

I have installed GitHub Desktop as the uploaded local project tool, I uploaded a project "F:/test", and it could show successful in my GitHub homepage, then I delete this repository.

But I re-publish this project to GitHub.

[image: show repo]

Github Desktop shows this history of the repository, and prompt error

```
 The repository does not seem to exist anymore. 
 You may not have [enter access, or it may have been deleted or renamed
```

[image: history with error message]

How can I get past this error message?

Comment: I had the same problem because I was not added as a contributor to the repository. I was added as a contributor using this instructions. https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository

Answer (score 14):

I was facing the same issue, I simply sign out from Github Desktop app in **File > options > Signout**

Comment: I don't understand how this worked for me. This answer looks like sarcastic but it actually worked xD

Answer (score 9):

This error was keeps on occurring to me. Turn out I was not added as the **Contributor** on the GitHub project.

The repo owner should be able to see and list of Contributor for the project. You can request him to add you in contributor list and this error will disappear.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I accidentally changed the push Url, so I executed:

```
git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

After that I checked with:

```
git remote show origin
```

your Fetch Url and Push Url must look like the same URL where you cloned the project.

Answer (score 2):

As shown [in this error](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1067), it is the result of an invalid local path. Either because it includes invalid characters, or because you don't have write/admin access to it (read access is not enough).

If you can, clone again that repo in a different path and [open it with GitHub Desktop](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/cloning-a-repository-from-github-to-github-desktop/), and see if the issue persists.

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/desktop/open-in-desktop-button.png]

Comment: @Brian Great! How was it resolved though? If this answer helped, consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thank You Bro I had only read access that is why i was not able to commit now all good :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have used more than one account. Just sign out from GitHub Desktop and sign in back to the specific account. You might sign out any logged GitHub session on the default web browser if the account is not what you want.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me. I hope they support multi account soon

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I deleted my repository from remote as well and then recreated.

If you aren't worried about the change trace being lost, then you can simply remove the .git folder (you will need to enable hidden files in windows) and then re-initialize the repository in the project folder.

This resolved the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

Since I had a forked repository, I had spelled **my url wrong** in

**github desktop -> repository -> repository settings...**

I had a link called `github.com/myname/myproject.it`

but instead of it I hade to write git.

```
github.com/myname/myproject.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to publish my local project to GitHub that already has some remotes currently configured for the repository.
Now to resolve this:
Step1: Show existing remotes

```
$ git remote -v
> origin    git@git-server/octocat/hello-world.git (fetch)
> origin    git@git-server/octocat/hello-world.git (push)
# Remove existing remotes
$ git remote remove origin
```

Step2:Add the repository to GitHub Desktop.

Step3:In the repository bar, click Publish repository.

resource: [GetHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/contributing-and-collaborating-using-github-desktop/adding-and-cloning-repositories/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-github-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a number of the above, I also had to fetch origin before I could push origin. I'm not sure which of the exact steps above were needed to allow the successful fetch.

Answer (score -1):

I was logged in with the wrong account! I had to sign out of Github in the browser first, then sign out in Github Desktop and re-sign in